# Как в JList изменить цвет выделенных строк

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить в `JList` цвет выделенных строк.

Как изменить цвет абсолютно всех строк - это понятно `list.setForeground(myColor)`, а вот как выделенных никак не могу додуматься.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вот как-то так. Нужно сделать новый `ListCellRenderer` и переопределить `getListCellRendererComponent`. Код стырил у [англоязычных коллег](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577010/980828).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ListText extends JFrame
{
    public ListText()
    {
        super("JList");
        String[] data = { "Lorem",
                "Ipsum",
                "Dolor",
                "Some",
                "Dummy",
                "Text",
                "Here"};
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(data);
        list.setCellRenderer(new NewListRenderer());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        addWindowListener(new ExitHandler());
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ListText();
    }

    private class NewListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
    {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                                                      int index, boolean isSelected,
                                                      boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, 
                                                        isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (isSelected) {
                c.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    private class ExitHandler extends WindowAdapter
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```